# Adjust listbox to display string longer than listbox width using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

In my listbox the strings are longer than the listbox width.

I cannot change the listbox width because of the already made up surface design:

[image]

Is there a VBA property for the listbox to:

> break the string in half and display it on more than one line

or

> scroll horizontally, to see the whole string

If there's not that kind of property, I'd like to know of other ideas.

Comment: What happens if you insert a return character CHR(13) or CHR(10)? Perhaps insert that if a length exceeds a certain amount?

Comment: Is that a Form Control or an ActiveX Control?

Comment: @AndyG ActiveX Control

Comment: @PGCodeRider Good idea, ill try that...let you know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListBox is single line only and does not support line breaks.

If it is an ActiveX then it has a property called `ColumnWidths`. Set it to something bigger like `500` and you will see a scrollbar at the bottom of the ListBox.